# Laravel Explode Array from Database

Tags: php, html, laravel, explode

In my database i have a text field of

```
"6:00 AM Registration Opens; Day of Race registration (if available), check-in, packet pick up. 7:30 AM - First Wave Start. 10:00 AM - Awards Ceremony (time is approximate)."
```

What I am trying to do is have it break everywhere there is a `.`

```
@foreach($eventDetails as $info)
 <p>{{explode('.', $info->eventSchedule)}}</p>
@endforeach
```

The error I keep getting is

```
"Array to string conversion"
```

Comment: Because as soon as you made it an array, you try to print it as a string again. You need to explode it then loop through the resultant array to print. Might be easier to str_replace `"."` with `".<br>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try str_replace() instead:

`<p>{{str_replace('.','.<br>', $info->eventSchedule)}}</p>`

Comment: This works, but I wouldn't consider it an answer that `solves` the problem.  It avoids it, in my opinion.  It could be a perfect solution depending on his scenario, though.

Comment: Thats what I thought, as there is no logic or processing of the array todo, it does what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

`explode('.', $info->eventSchedule)` returns an array() of strings.  In blade templating engine (which Laravel uses), anything in double brackets `{{ 'Hello world' }}` is converted to and echo statement `<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>`.

You cannot echo an array, so `<?php echo explode('.', $info->eventSchedule); ?>` fails.  I'm not sure exactly your goal, but I would try this:

```
@foreach($eventDetails as $info)
    @foreach(explode('.', $info->eventSchedule) as $string)
        {{ $string }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This will now loop through the array created by `explode()`, and echo the String through blade's templating engine.